# Anyone know what LaTeX font settings produce both written text AND mathematical text like in the following picture?

Tags: fonts

Anyone know what LaTeX font settings produce both written text AND mathematical text like in the following picture? I am trying to reproduce these notes in LaTeX with zero visual changes (especially to the way the math looks). Thanks!

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: https://openlearninglibrary.mit.edu/assets/courseware/v1/9d904854b4ae0878cfdcedcdceabf937/asset-v1:MITx+6.036+1T2019+type@asset+block/notes_chapter_Linear_classifiers.pdf  just uses default computer modern and ams fonts

Comment: Looks like Palatino text font and a mixture of math fonts, including Euler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2] $\mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{H}$ \textit{learning algorithm}
\end{document}
```